# Check code compatibility for different PHP versions

Tags: php, phpstan

I am searching for a way to check my PHP code for compatibility with different PHP versions.
Especially compatibility to PHP version 7.2 - 8.1 is what I am looking for. At first I tried **phpcs** but the results were not really good, so I tried something different.

To test the code I introduced **phpstan** which works really well (for one PHP version) but it seems it is only possible to specify one PHP version per configuration.

My phpstan.neon file:

```
parameters:
        level: 0
        phpVersion: 70400
        paths:
                - src/project
                - src/library
```

Running `vendor/bin/phpstan -c phpstan.neon` works as expected.

Tried to specify more than one value for `phpVersion` but this only produces an error because the argument has to be int|null value.

Does anyone know a method to check more than one PHP vesion in just one run of phpstan? Maybe there is an appropriate rule set for different PHP versions?

Answer (score 0):

You must use a phpstan conditional configuration. It is achieved by including a php conditional php version checker in main phpstan configuration.

In phpstan.neon, add:

```
includes:
- phpstan.conditional.php
```

In phpstan.conditional.php, add:

```
<?php declare(strict_types = 1);

/**
 * Add conditionally extra phpstan rules
 * Typically used for specific PHP versions
 * Must be called in main PHPStan neon config file
 */

$includes = [];

// For versions smaller that PHP 8.3.
if (PHP_VERSION_ID < 80300) {
    $includes[] = __DIR__ . '/phpstan-rules-lt-8.3.neon';
}

$config = [];
$config['includes'] = $includes;
$config['parameters']['phpVersion'] = PHP_VERSION_ID;

return $config;
```

Then add your specific rules for PHP version smaller than PHP 8.3 into phpstan-rules-lt-8.3.neon

When executing PHPStan on PHP < 8.3 environment, those rules will apply. When executing PHPStan on PHP => 8.3 environment, the rules won't be executed.